# How to resume prediction(testing) after modifying a hidden layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What I want to test is what is the difference of the output before and after I modify the last hidden layer values.

So I can divide my question in two parts

1. First

```
last_hidden_layer_values=[1,2,3,4,5]
And I want to set it into:
my_hidden_layer_values=[1,1,1,1,1]
```

2. Second:

After modifying **last_hidden_layer_values** into **my_hidden_layer_values**, how can I assume the model prediction?

I'm using tensorflow to evaluate this, but I am new to it. I have searched this a little bit. Is `tf.train.Checkpoint` the answer? But it seems like it is only for training?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two different models: one with the original hidden layer values, and one with the altered hidden layer values. If you want to compare the different predictions of these two models on some prediction, you can use the [predict](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) method here.

i.e. something like

```
model_1.predict(input_x)
# and
model_2.predict(input_x)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i see..., but how can I modify a specific hidden layer values?

Comment: Do you already have values that you want to insert manually? In that case you can use the [```set_weights```](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights) method. For example, if you modifying the values in a Dense layer, you can set its weights values and bias values with ```layer.set_weights([weights, biases])```

Comment: I am doing this under testing phase, so my model is trained. and  what i want to do is to set the activation value of my model. is there a function for me to modify activation values?

Comment: I'm not very sure what you mean by setting the activation value. But you can specify the activation function (which have different activation values) for your layers with an argument, see the [Dense layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) for an example. Or you can specifically add an [Activation layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Activation). If you want more numerical control, you could also modify the bias and weight values to use some function other than ```output = activation(dot(input, kernel) + bias)```.